# K8s pod memory limitation aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, memory-management, containers, kubernetes-pod

I had a pod with a
request memory to 2
and a limit memory up to 3.5

We get some massive request rate and the pod stays up with 7.5 memory usage.

How we can explain that?

Comment: COuld you please share more information, like your Kubernetes pod YAML etc?

Comment: show ``kubectrl top pod`` and the pod manifest.  I think you are mistaken

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#how-pods-with-resource-limits-are-run

Comment: Limit does not work like that . Check above url for official doc